# Lighttpd: Videos not streaming properly

Tags: video-streaming, lighttpd

I am streaming my videos through port 81, however, when I click on the middle of a video I do not get what I was expecting (forwarding). Does this have to do with my lighttpd installation, or with the software I am using? I am using a framework where all that has to be done is set a '1' on a lighttpd streaming value, and it should be good to go if lighttpd is installed correctly (in fact I already did this for another installation and worked, and I don't know what's the problem now).

I am using lighttpd 1.5 on CentOS. Streaming through port 81. Here are some of the lines that I added to lighttpd.conf and modules.conf: http://paste.lighttpd.net/2517

From what I can see in firebug, the video is being streamed through mydomain.com:81. The Live HTTP headers of Firefox also show no problem; they display the video being streamed using lighttpd and octet/stream as application.

Any input that could help me deal with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you streaming the video or just downloading a movie file? (What's the content type set for?)

Comment: streaming the video. The content-type is not set, it's the default. Video is in .flv and appears as octet/stream in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, yet quite interesting since I had to solve the very same problem.

Lighttpd doesn't support forwarding / pseudo streaming inherently when you don't use the HTML5 player.

You need to add a module for lighttpd, which can be found here:
http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki

You will have to merge some files build lighttpd by yourself, its written on their website.
Don't use the sources of lighttpd-1-4-18, you won't be able to build because of a bug, use 1.4.28 instead.

Also interesting: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html